# Before_Action not being called for controller Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to redirect user accounts who have `user.account_delinquent = true`. The issue is, the account is still able to access the test controller even though the helper method is active.

My controller has included `ApplicationHelper` with a `before_action :account_delinquency`, but the method refuses to fire.

How can I properly setup my `account_delinquency` helper method to fire a redirect if the `current_user.account_delinquent == true`?

My code is below:

**magazines_controller.rb**

```
class MagazinesController < ApplicationController
  include ApplicationHelper
  before_action :account_delinquency

  def index
    @magazines = Magazine.all
  end
end
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
def account_delinquency
  if user_signed_in? || employer_signed_in?
    redirect_to update_account_index_path, alert: 'We were unable to charge your account' if current_user.account_delinquent == true || current_employer.account_delinquent == true
  end
end
```

Comment: a helper is for views and not for controller methods

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `account_delinquency` in `ApplicationController`, not in `ApplicationHelper`. I always put before actions in a controller, never in a helper.

Comment: I will report back tomorrow after trying your approach.

Comment: Make it a private (or protected) method of the controller. Also, you can tell rails to only call the `account_deliquency` method before certain actions (i.e. not before all actions) like this: `before_action :account_deliquency, only: [:index]`

Comment: @JohnnyC it is not his approach, but the way to go

Comment: I believe my latest approach will be the simplest to keep track of, in the long run. Since I have to use it across controllers. Plus, it effects the entire controller, just not the views. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the helper method working by syncing the user_session to the user variable itself. Since, this method will only be used for logged in members.

application_helper.rb

```
def account_delinquency
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_session(session[:user_id])
    redirect_to update_account_index_path, alert: 'We were unable to charge your account' if @current_user.account_delinquent
  end
```

controller.rb

```
class MagazinesController < ApplicationController
    include ApplicationHelper
    before_action :account_delinquency
end
```